# Display a query with name salary and commission for all employees

Tags: sql

I have a question about SQL - this is my code so far:

```
SELECT ename,sal,comm
FROM emp
ORDER BY sal,comm  desc;
WHERE comm>0;
```

I need to display the name, salary and commission for all employees who earn commission, and sort the data out in descending order of salary and commission.

Comment: Try reading the documentation for where the parts of the `select` statement should go.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `;` in your query, and you need to rearrange things:

```
Select ename,sal,comm from emp order by sal,comm desc; where comm>0;
```

should be

```
Select ename,sal,comm from emp where comm>0 order by sal,comm desc;
```

Comment: Probably should be `order by sal desc,comm desc` as the question states "sort the data out in descending order of salary and commission."

Comment: @MartinSmith isn't the `sal desc` assumed when written `sal,comm desc`?

Comment: @Eonasdan - No. the `desc` only applies to the preceding expression not the whole list.

Comment: @MartinSmith oooh! right it's `asc` that doesn't need to be expletive.

Answer (score 0):

you should use order clause at last

```
Select ename,sal,comm from emp where comm>0 order by sal,comm desc;
```

this should be your query also see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) for further knowledge on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ename,sal,comm from emp where comm>0 order by sal,comm desc;
```

What about that?